# write function not reading timer

Tags: javascript, timer

I'm trying to write a timer function. In its first state, the timer worked, but the code it executed had to be placed within the timer, inside the `goActive/goInactive` functions respectively. Now I'm trying to separate the timer from the function calls by having `goActive/goInactive` return little signal variables, which other code blocks can interpret.

Right now I've just got a simple mock-up. I want `goActive` and `goInactive` to return 1 or -1, and then another function, `checktimer`, ought to write them to the screen as they update. But I've not figured out the logic. I'm very new to JS; I appreciate all help:

```js
var TimeoutID;
var timerstatus = 0;

function inputdetect() {
  // attaches event handler to specified event
  // takes event as string, function to run, and optional boolean
  // to indicate when the event propogates
  // these are false, so events "bubble up"
  this.addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer, false);
  this.addEventListener("mousedown", resetTimer, false);
  this.addEventListener("mousewheel", resetTimer, false);
  this.addEventListener("keypress", resetTimer, false);
  this.addEventListener("touchmove", resetTimer, false);
  this.addEventListener("DOMmousescroll", resetTimer, false);
  this.addEventListener("MSpointermove", resetTimer, false);

  startTimer();
}

inputdetect();

function startTimer() {
  //waits two seconds before calling inactive
  TimeoutID = window.setTimeout(goInactive, 2000); // does it need to take the window variable??
}

function resetTimer(e) {
  window.clearTimeout(TimeoutID);
  goActive();
}

function goActive() {
  //what happens when the UI is not idle

  $('#hi').text("The UI is not idle.");
  timerstatus = 1;
  $('#var').text(timerstatus);

  startTimer();
  return timerstatus;
}

function goInactive() {
  $('#hi').text("The UI is idle.");
  timerstatus = -1;
  $('#var').text(timerstatus);
  return timerstatus;
  // REPLACING CURSOR WHEN UI IS IDLE
  //this part won't work
}

function checktimer(timerstatus) {
  $('#ct').text(timerstatus);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  window.setInterval(checktimer(timerstatus), 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>check timer update goes: <span id="ct"></p></div>

<!--this is where the HTML will go*/-->
<p id = "hi">hello</p>
<p id = "ts">Timer status is: <span id = "var"></span> 
  </p>
```

Comment: It seems to work ok in the snippet ... it outputs: `check timer update goes: 0 | The UI is not idle. | Timer status is: 1` ... and that changes when idle for 2 secs. ... What should the wanted output look like?

Comment: Yeah, seems to work properly here as well. Here's a jsfiddle you can play with: https://jsfiddle.net/v8zzwLpL/1/ Just move your mouse around over the results section to see it in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect.

```
window.setInterval(checktimer(timerstatus), 2000);
```

You need to pass a function instead of invoking one.

Because `timerstatus` is a global variable, it's already shared by all the functions, so you don't need to pass and return it. All the functions can just use it.

So just pass `checktimer` to `setInterval`.

```
window.setInterval(checktimer, 2000);
```

Get rid of all the `return timerstatus;` lines, and get rid of the parameter for `checktimer`:

```
function checktimer() {
  $('#ct').text(timerstatus);
}
```

I don't know if this does what you ultimately want, but it does correct the code.